# hi! can you recommend a good basic tutorial for Craft?

Tags: admin

can anyone recommend a good video or any tutorial for Craft? Thanks

Comment: Hi Jon, check out the resources mentioned in the linked post.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these sites are run by Ryan Irelan

https://mijingo.com/craft

https://craftquest.io/